# Weird error when using MongoDebugPanel in Flask DebugToolbar

Tags: mongodb, flask, flask-mongoengine

I am getting this weird error which is driving me kinda nuts when I try and add the MongoDebugPanel to my Flask DebugToolbar extension:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Personal Backups/CodingProjects/HTML_Projects/MongoEngine/app.py", line 17, in <module>
    toolbar = DebugToolbarExtension(app)
  File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask_debugtoolbar\__init__.py", line 58, in __init__
    self.init_app(app)
  File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask_debugtoolbar\__init__.py", line 72, in init_app
    DebugToolbar.load_panels(app)
  File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask_debugtoolbar\toolbar.py", line 50, in load_panels
    for panel_class in cls._iter_panels(app):
  File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask_debugtoolbar\toolbar.py", line 57, in _iter_panels
    panel_class = cls._import_panel(app, panel_path)
  File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask_debugtoolbar\toolbar.py", line 71, in _import_panel
    panel_class = import_string(path)
  File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\utils.py", line 418, in import_string
    __import__(import_name)
  File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask_mongoengine\panels.py", line 5, in <module>
    from flask_mongoengine import operation_tracker
  File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask_mongoengine\operation_tracker.py", line 26, in <module>
    '_unpack_response': pymongo.helpers._unpack_response,
AttributeError: module 'pymongo.helpers' has no attribute '_unpack_response'
```

Anyone perhaps know what could be the reason for this? I am at my wits end trying to write something that even remotely works with Mongo+Flask...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a known bug ([Issue #325](https://github.com/MongoEngine/flask-mongoengine/issues/325)) related to a newer version of PyMongo. Reverting to 3.5.1 is the current workaround.

If you run `pip install pymongo==3.5.1`, the MongoDebugPanel will work again.

Comment: or upgrade to flask-mongoengine 1.0

Answer (score 1):

@Ants 
flask-mongoengine was not maintained for several years, but now this fixed in current master with MR https://github.com/MongoEngine/flask-mongoengine/pull/372